# Authenticating private repositories when running docker/compose in container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-container-optimized-os

I'm using GCP's container-optimized image to run a number of containers through docker compose. As mentioned in [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os) article, public repositories are working fine but I can't figure out why `docker login` in the host machine is not reflected in the `docker-compose` container.

```
docker login -u "bohemia" -p"randompass" docker.coolregistry.com
```

which gives:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/bohemia/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
```

I'm not using any credential helper, so mounting the path to the docker config (with the updated token) to the container running compose should work.

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" \
    -v "$HOME/.docker/config.json:$HOME/.docker/config.json" \
    -v "$PWD:$PWD" \
    -w="$PWD" \
    docker/compose:1.24.0 up -d
```

But I'm still getting the following error:

```
...
Pulling container (docker.coolregistry.com/this_image:latest)...
ERROR: Get https://docker.coolregistry.com/v2/this_image/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you running the `docker run` command? Container OS does not maintain changes across reboots. More details are required.

Comment: @JohnHanley This code will be saved in the gcp meta servers as startup script. The idea is to start the instance and run the docker-compose.yml  file to spawn containers. Let me know what details would be of help.

Comment: The startup script does not use your user's $HOME.